# Unique field in pymongo

Tags: flask, pymongo

What is the simplest way to avoid field collisions working with pymongo? I have a very simple structure for a Location class (name, slug, description and geolocation) and I would like to ensure that no duplicate names are allowed. I am using flask and pymongo?

I was trying this:

```
from flask import Flask

from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo


app = Flask(__name__)

mongo = PyMongo(app)

mongo.db.court.ensureIndex( { "name": 1, "slug": 1 } )
```

but it gives me an error: RuntimeError: working outside of application context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [unique indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#unique-indexes) and you'll have no two documents that have same values for a field. this doesn't have to be flask-specific, but it is rather mongodb-specific.

if you're lazy or indexes give you headache, just use `_id` field as the location name. in this case you have to make sure your documents don't get overwritten.

Comment: I undestood this, thank you, and I get it that it is mongo specific, but I would like to do it directly in Flask, since I do not want to use an ORM like mongoengine or mongokit. Basically I want to avoid models completely and roll just with view functions, insert directly via pymongo. My question is where do I put this index code

Comment: @freethrow You don't need `flask-pymongo` to update the databases. they exist for reducing the pain of managing db connections upon requests. use `pymongo` directly and you won't need any context.

Answer (score 4):

The best place to put your calls to `ensure_index` is someplace before you call `run()` on your flask app. You want to make sure your indexes are in place before you attempt to service any requests, because building the index while the site is live will make it pretty unresponsive. The error you are getting is because you need the application context. Try:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
mongo = PyMongo(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        mongo.db.court.ensure_index( [("name", ASCENDING), ("slug", ASCENDING)], unique=True )
    app.run()
```

As @thkang said, you should use a unique index to enforce that no two documents have the same value for a field or set of fields taken together. See more about this and pymongo's `ensure_index` syntax at the [pymongo docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.ensure_index).

Answer (score 3):

*ensure_index* has been [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/). Use *[create_index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex)* instead.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import pymongo

app = Flask(__name__)
mongo = PyMongo(app)

with app.app_context():
    mongo.db.court.create_index([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("slug", pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)
```

Comment: how do i check if there is already a created index? to not create it again